# Rename PowerPoint custom Tab name depending on PowerPoint Version

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint, office-addins

I have created a plug-in for PowerPoint 2010 and later versions.

I have to keep the custom tab label in lowercase in PowerPoint 2010 while that in uppercase in later versions.

Now, I am using below code in the InitializeComponent() method in MyRibbon.Designer.cs file

```
if (Convert.ToDouble(Globals.ThisAddIn.strVersion) == 14.0)
{
    this.tab1.Label = "myTab";
}
else if (Convert.ToDouble(Globals.ThisAddIn.strVersion) > 14.0)
{
    this.tab1.Label = "MYTAB";
}
```

However, I want to decide the tab label somewhere else and then use it in the designer class file.

But I know that InitializeComponent() is the first method to be called and this is causing all the trouble.

I have used "Globals.ThisAddIn.strVersion" as I have to use this multiple times throughout the project solution.

Please suggest.
Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you have? You could use the Startup event of your addin and set the label there.

Comment: Mitja, the problem is that AFAIK, the InitializeComponent() method is called before the StartUp event. So, I am not getting how to set the label in StartUp, if the ribbon is initialized before the StartUp.
I tried accessing the tab in ThisAddin_Startup to rename it, however, its not working..

Comment: This code won't work on a French OS because ToDouble chokes on a string such as "14.0".   Try this: Convert.ToDouble(Globals.ThisAddIn.strVersion, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me-

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.tab1.label = "myTab";
}
```

Also in the Ribbon Load event handler, add the following code:

```
private void Ribbon_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
{
    objRibUI = e.RibbonUI;
    objRibUI.Invalidate();
}
```

The tab text case is automatically taken care of.
Cheers.

Comment: In the Ribbon_Load event just place the code posted in the original  question. Thats all one needs.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
// Setting up the startup event
private void InternalStartup(){
    this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
}

// The event handler
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e){
    Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.tab1.Label = Convert.ToDouble(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Version) <= 14 ? "myTab" : "MYTAB";
}
```

Or you could also try the ribbon load event:

```
// Hook up the handler in InitializeComponents
this.Load += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonUIEventHandler(this.Ribbon1_Load);

// The handler
private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e){
    tab1.Label = Convert.ToDouble(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Version) <= 14 ? "myTab" : "MYTAB";
}
```

Comment: I have tried both the options, but unfortunately, no luck.

However, I solved the issue at my end using the code I have added in the original question...Please check if this works for you or not?
Thanks..

Comment: Shared the code that worked for me as an answer to the question.